# How to get touch coordinates before presenting a popover?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

In my code I need to get the coordinates of a touch before to present a popover.
This is the code:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped:)];
[tapRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[tapRecognizer setDelegate:self];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
FreeAndNil(tapRecognizer);

ratingSliderViewController = [[CMRatingSliderViewController alloc] init];
ratingPopoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:ratingSliderViewController];
[ratingPopoverController setDelegate:self];
[ratingPopoverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(360.0, 50.0)];
[self setPopoverController:ratingPopoverController];
[ratingPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(latestTouchPoint.x, latestTouchPoint.y, 10.0,10.0) inView:detailView permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];

[self.view removeGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];


...

}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    latestTouchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
}
```

However the popover is presented before the `touchesBegan` invocation. How can I solve this? I would prefer to not use delays or run the popover code in the generic `touchesBegan` method.

Comment: I don't understand - you just add gesture to a view, and then showing a pop over. Why do you think the pop over will be presented before the touchesBegan? the touchesBegan will be called only when the user touch the self.view...

Comment: @AviTsadok I've actually realized that touchesBegan is never invoked, but I can't figure out what's wrong in my code

Comment: First of all, touchesBegan is a UIView method, not a View Controller method, that is why its never called. Secondly, if you added tap gesture, why do you need to overide the touchesBegan method (Which you did in the wrong place)?

Comment: @AviTsadok OK. I was wrong about using touchesBegan, since I'm in a UIViewController. What's the best way to get touch coordinate? I'm now trying to use - (void)getCoordinates:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer method, triggered by the UITapGestureRecognizer, but it is never invoked as well.

Comment: You can just use the [tapRecognizer locationInView:] method. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First add the gesture recognizer when the view loads.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer;


 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped:)];
    [_tapRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:_tapRecognizer];
}
```

Also make sure that you present the popover inside the tap recognizer handler function instead of when you declare it (as you do now)!

```
-(void) tapRecognizer:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tabRecognizer{

     CGPoint touchedPoint = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.view];
     NSLog(@"Point x %f x %f", aPoint.x, aPoint.y);

     ratingSliderViewController = [[CMRatingSliderViewController alloc] init];
     ratingPopoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:ratingSliderViewController];
     [ratingPopoverController setDelegate:self];
     [ratingPopoverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(360.0, 50.0)];
     [self setPopoverController:ratingPopoverController];
     [ratingPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(touchedPoint,     touchedPoint, 10.0,10.0) inView:detailView   permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get by using this delegate method add delegate to gestures,

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution (requiring some javascript) here: http://www.mindfirelabs.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=142